# how can i call one function from another function in same controller in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I tried to call one function from another function but I got a error which is:

```
2angular.js:9193 Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$interpolate/interr?p0=%0A%20%20%20%20%0A…()%7D%7D%0A%0A%20%20&p1=TypeError%3A%20undefined%20is%20not%20a%20function
```

i Write following code in html file

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="SomeController">

     {{ini()}}

  <div id='bar' >
<div id='slider'>

</div>
</div>
```

And my controller looks like:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {

    $scope.bar =document.getElementById('bar');
    $scope.slider =document.getElementById('slider');
    $scope.info = document.getElementById('info');
    $scope.set_per="";
    $scope.ini = function() {
        $scope.bar.addEventListener('mousedown', $scope.startSlide(), false);   
        $scope.bar.addEventListener('mouseup', $scope.stopSlide(), false);
    }

    $scope.startslide=function(event){

        $scope.set_perc = ((((event.clientX - $scope.bar.offsetLeft) / $scope.bar.offsetWidth)).toFixed(2));
        info.innerHTML = 'start' + $scope.set_perc+ '%';    
        $scope.bar.addEventListener('mousemove', $scope.moveSlide(bar,slider,info), false); 
        $scope.slider.style.width = ($scope.set_perc * 100) + '%';  
     }

    $scope.moveSlide=function(event){
        $scope.set_perc = ((((event.clientX - $scope.bar.offsetLeft) / $scope.bar.offsetWidth)).toFixed(2));
        $scope.info.innerHTML = 'moving : ' + $scope.set_perc + '%';
        $scope.slider.style.width = ($scope.set_perc * 100) + '%';
    }

    $scope.stopSlide=function(event){
        $scope.set_perc = ((((event.clientX - $scope.bar.offsetLeft) / $scope.bar.offsetWidth)).toFixed(2));
        $scope.info.innerHTML = 'done : ' + $scope.set_perc + '%';
        $scope.bar.removeEventListener('mousemove', $scope.moveSlide(bar,slider,info), false);
        $scope.slider.style.width = ($scope.set_perc * 100) + '%';
    }

});
```

Comment: Downvoted because of poor formatting for the question. If you fix the formatting I will upvote and provide an answer.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, angular seems like the wrong tool... You are doing DOM manipulation in the controller. You are also calling native functions for attaching handlers to elements (and not passing an actual function reference, but invoking the functions instead). You wouldn't normally call {{ini()}} from template as you are not displaying a value in the {{}}, but just using it to add event listeners (again a bad thing to do in controllers).

Comment: @Patrick is correct in many ways!

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is to use a service. You should really look into directives to solve the problem based on the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

You're trying to call `$scope.startSlide()` when it is defined `$scope.startslide`, notice the capital S.

Also I would strongly encourage you to read Patrick's comment which points out several abuses of the angularjs framework.